# power loss calculation

Tags: power, batteries

I was reading StevenVH's response to the post [How long will it take...](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34884/how-long-will-it-take-to-completely-run-out-of-power-for-two-a23-batties12volt) and he brought up something I was completely unfamiliar with; the power loss associated with the large volt difference between the battery and the LED. His calculation was very straight forward.

My question is: where can I find more information on this? I have googled this topic and so far have come up with no other sources.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fundamental principle in electrical engineering, if you have a 2-lead device like a resistor, the power used by the device is equal to voltage across the device times current through the device.

\$P = IV\$

If the current flows through the device from the higher-voltage side to the lower voltage side, the device is consuming power (or dissipating it as heat). If the current flows through the device from the lower-voltage side to the higher voltage side (for example, if the device is a battery or power supply) then we consider the current to have a negative sign (for example, -10 mA) and the device is delivering power to the rest of the circuit.

Wikipedia has a page on [electric power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power), but it quickly gets into more complex cases (like AC circuits) because for DC it really just boils down to this one equation.